# How To Extract Function Name From Main() Function Of C Source

Tags: c++, function, extract

I just want to ask your ideas regarding this matter. For a certain important reason, I must extract/acquire all function names of functions that were called inside a "main()" function of a C source file (ex: main.c).

Example source code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = functionA(); // functionA must be extracted
    int b = functionB(); // functionB must be extracted
}
```

As you know, the only thing that I can use as a marker/sign to identify these function calls are it's parenthesis "()". I've already considered several factors in implementing this function name extraction. These are:
1. functions may have parameters. Ex: functionA(100)
2. Loop operators. Ex: while()
3. Other operators. Ex: if(), else if()
4. Other operator between function calls with no spaces. Ex: functionA()+functionB()

As of this moment I know what you're saying, this is a pain in the $$$... So please share your thoughts and ideas... and bear with me on this one...

Note: this is in C++ language...

Comment: What about calls through function pointers?

Comment: Do you need the name of the functions who never get called? Example: `if (0) Function()`

Comment: What do you mean you have to "extract" them? Do you mean parse, or do you mean from a particular run look at the call-graph? For the latter you can just use valgrind, as it'll output the call-graph and you can then see what was called from main.  The format is standard so you can even write a tool to extract that bit of the call graph.

Comment: @pts: yes Sir I need to consider it... thanks!

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: it is Parse Sir! thanks!

Comment: Is that `main()` function really so large that you cannot scan it with your eyes faster than coming up with a tool??

Answer (score 3):

You can write a Small C++ parser by combining FLEX (or LEX) and BISON (or YACC).

1. Take C++'s grammar
2. Generate a C++ program parser with the mentioned tools
3. Make that program count the funcion calls you are mentioning

Maybe a little bit too complicated for what you need to do, but it should certainly work. And LEX/YACC are amazing tools!

Comment: Thanks Pablo! Honestly I don't a clue of what LEX/YACC is.. So I will research it. Regarding your number 3 instruction, I don't get what you want to tell me..

Comment: You will write a program (mostly) generated by FLEX and BISON. You will be able to identify function calls in that program very easily. That's point #3.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write your own C tokenizer (simple: just be careful enough to skip over strings, character constants and comments), and to write a simple parser, which counts the number of `{`s open, and finds instances of identifier + `(` within. However, this won't be 100% correct. The disadvantage of this option is that it's cumbersome to implement preprocessor directives (e.g. `#include` and `#define`): there can be a function called from a macro (e.g. `getchar`) defined in an `#include` file.

An option that works for 100% is compiling your `.c` file to an assembly file, e.g. `gcc -S file.c`, and finding the `call` instructions in the `file.S`. A similar option is compiling your `.c` file to an object file, e.g, `gcc -c file.c`, generating a disassembly dump with `objdump -d file.o`, and searching for `call` instructions.

Another option is finding a parser using Clang / LLVM.

Comment: @Hisoka: If you find my answer useful, please vote it up (by clicking to the /\ up arrow to the left of the answer) after you gain 15 reputation in total.

Answer (score 2):

gnu `cflow` might be helpful

Comment: thanks sir jokester! but what I specifically need to do is just create a simple C++ code to parse all function names... but thanks again for your answer Sir...